# How to show exact solution of Finite Difference Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The question requires me to show the exact solution of the finite difference equation$$y''=k^2y$$for $-1<x<1$, $y(-1)=y(1)=1$ and $k>0$.

Given the difference formula$$y''(x_i)=\frac{1}{h^2}[y(x_{i+1})-2y(x_i)+y(x_{i-1})]-O(h^2),$$
and what I can get is $$y_{i+1}-(2+k^2h^2)y_i+y_{i-1}=h^2f_i.$$
How can I show the exact solution of $y_i$ in terms of $x_i$?

Comment: Title & tag say *differential* equation, body says *difference* equation. Please edit for consistency.

Comment: What do you know about characteristic polynomials?

Comment: the roots are -k or k

Comment: I'm confused by what your'e asking, the $f_i$ isn't stated in the original ODE, where has it come from? Are you trying to solve explicitly in terms of $y_i$ in your difference equaiton?

Comment: Title edited, thank you, but tag still says differential equations.

Comment: both of them are correct

Comment: my question in under the topic (differential equation)

Comment: fxi should be 0

Comment: i used recurrence relation but still cant get the required ans